# Accented Characters don't display properly

Tags: d3.js

I'm having some trouble with the accented characters.
I'm importing a in the tsv function txt with tab separated value. 
The file is generated from excel using "save as" "text tab separated"
I think it is a problem with the charset.

- You can see the d3 chart here: http://www.danielepennati.com/d3/stacked_bar_vert.html
- The txt file is this one: http://www.danielepennati.com/d3/data/set500_sez1_graf1.txt

I need to have an output directly from excel that support the accented character.
Do you have any advice?

Comment: Make sure you tell Excel to export as UTF-8.

Comment: Specifically, save as "Unicode text (*.txt)".

Comment: In Excel (I've the italian version...) these are the option I have to save as: http://www.danielepennati.com/d3/excel.png I've tried to save as Text Unicode (only utf-16 is avaible... not utf-8...)
I've added a new chart in the previouse link colling the txt save as unicode utf-8 (the 2nd one)
http://www.danielepennati.com/d3/stacked_bar_vert.html  In Chrome it works fine, but in firefox the 2nd chart is broken because the txt isn't correcly read and d3.js doesn't elaborate it.

Why? do you have any idea?

There are other way to save as utf-8 in excel?

Answer (score 1):

Your text file has charset ISO-8859-1, save it with encoding UTF-8 and reload your page.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent the last day trying to save from excel with utf8 encoding...
after this losing of time I'm still not able to export utf8 directly from excel.
Your answers make me thinking that I'm the only one with this problem. Do you get a txt or csv in utf8 from excel? what do you set to have this output?

At the end I've follow a 2 step workflow:
- export from excel as text unicode
- open the txt in a code editor sw and change the encoding to utf8

now the file is read correctly on all the browser (no more issue like firefox and utf16)
here the updated page with 3 txt data file (firs is the output of the "tab separated", the 2nd il "text unicode" and the last is the "text unicode" re-encoded with 3rd part sw)
http://www.danielepennati.com/d3/stacked_bar_vert.html

If you know how to set uft8 inside excel I'll really appreciate
Thanks
Daniele